# What cascade-type to use, to save only the list of children of a many-to-many mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Assume entity classes Foo and Bar like:

```
class Foo {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "FooBar",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "foo"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bar"))
    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

}

class Bar {
    // ...
}
```

When I save a Foo entity, I want to save bars list also, but only the mapping list, for example:

```
Bar oldBar = foo.getBars().get(0);
oldBar.setSomething("new-value"); // Change to the entity.

Bar newbar = new Bar();
foo.getBars().add(newbar);  // Change to the list.

saveOrUpdate(foo);
```

I want `saveOrUpdate` persist the changes to the list, but not changes to the entity. Can I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CascadeType.PERSIST` sort of does what you want, but it depends on the starting state of your foo object.  If the old foo is in the managed state, then changes you make to oldBar are persistent.  That can't really be 'turned off.'  Why would you change a value on a persistent object if it's not supposed to get changed?  It doesn't really make sense in an ORM context.

Comment: Well, I don't want to change oldBar, but its properties are touched, so get dirty maybe. And its `lastModifiedDate`  is updated by some utility functions.

Comment: Right.  What I was saying is, if an Entity's persistent fields get changed, the expectation is those changes go into the database.  If it's getting "dirty" with things that aren't supposed to end up in the DB, that's a higher level issue with the design.